# Running commands in remote linux from java

Tags: java, linux, shell, ssh

I want to do a remote shell to a Linux system and run various commands e.g. to `ps` and `grep` for processes and kill them.
I assume I can do something like: `rsh` that linux scripts do right?Is this the best option for me?

Comment: [JSCH](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`rsh` is unencrypted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Shell) so isn't widely used anymore and is probably switched off on the remote systems you want to connect to.

It would be better to [use `SSH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell).  [JSch is a open source pure Java library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) that will make SSH connections and run commands for you.

Answer (score 0):

JSch is a good choice to do such kind of tasks.